# Unprotect ranges if it meets a criteria on script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to unprotect certain cells if they meet a criteria, there are 600 rows and 36 columns in total. Somehow, these coding only work up to 100 row. If I were to replace it with `row = 600`, it exceeds maximum time.

How could I better write this script so that it will run? Also, as I'm new to using Google app script, how could I paste my codes in a grey block? I have paste currently as per below:

```
var rows = 687
var columns = 36
var unprotectedRange = new Array()
var myRange = new Array()
var myRangeCells = sheet.getRange(1,1,rows,columns)
for (i = 1;i < rows;i++)
{
   for (j = 1; j<columns;j++)
   {
      var curCell = myRangeCells.getCell(i,j)
      var myColour = curCell.getBackground()
      if (myColour == '#ffffcc' || myColour == '#ffff99')
      {
         unprotectedRange.push(curCell)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help to learn about how to format posts. If you have more questions on how to use this site, please post a question on [meta].

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the cells backgrounds cell by cell, get all the backgrounds on one call by using getBackgrounds() instead of getBackground(). Example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var numRows = 687;
  var numColumns = 36;
  var array = new Array;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns);

  // Get all the backgrounds with one call
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();

  // Loop through all range cells to check which meet the unprotection criteria
  for(var row=1; row<=numRows; row++){
    for(var column=1; column<=numColumns; column++){
      var background = backgrounds[row-1][column-1];
      if(background == '#ffffcc' || background == '#ffff99'){
        var cell = range.getCell(row, column);
        array.push(cell);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(array.length);
}
```